# Random Variables Software

Tags: random-variables, math-software

Is there some softaware that deals with random variables as objects?

For example, suppose I define some i.i.d. random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n\in N(0,1)$, where $N(0,1)$ is the normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. After that, I could want to calculates something like $$E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_iX_j,\Big)$$

In this particular case, I know that $E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_iX_j,\Big) = E\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\Big) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i^2) = n$. For more complicated expressions (with others distributions) could happen to be more moments, in this case the program just let the terms uncalculated. Or maybe, if random variables are objects, could be a way to define higher moments.

Anyone knows some software that does this?

Thank you.

PS: Its supposed to be a software that works in a symbolic way, I dont want numeric approximations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wrote:

> I know that $E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_iX_j,\Big) = E\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\Big)$

While that is correct for the special case of the N(0,1) in your example, some care should be taken by the passing reader to note that it is not generally correct, because $E[X Y] \ne E[X^2]$ (even if $X$ and $Y$ are independent). A more general valid expression would be:

$$E\Big(\sum_{i,j=1}^n X_i X_j\Big)  = E\Big [\Big (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\Big)^2\Big ]  $$

To answer your question re software:  the *mathStatica* software package for *Mathematica* provides a suite of specialised *moment of moment* functions that provide exactly this functionality (I am one of the authors).

For examples, see Chapter 7 of our book:

- Rose and Smith,  "*Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica*", Springer, NY

A free download of the chapter is available here:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/Rose_and_Smith_2002edition_Chapter7.pdf

Comment: I think you misundertand, let me give you some examples to clarify.
$$E(\sum_{i,j=1}^2X_iX_j) = E(X_1^2+2X_1X_2+X_2^2) = E(X_1^2)+2E(X_1X_2)+E(X_2^2)$$
but $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, so $2E(X_1X_2)=2E(X_1)E(X_2)=2\cdot0\cdot0=0$, therefore
$$E(\sum_{i,j=1}^2X_iX_j) = E(X_1^2)+E(X_2^2) =\sum_{i=1}^2 E(X_i^2)$$

For $n=3$ we get
$$E(\sum_{i,j=1}^2X_iX_j) = E(X_1^2+2X_1X_2+2X_1X_3+2X_2X_3+X_2^2+X_3^2) =$$ $$= E(X_1^2)+E(X_2^2)+E(X_3^2) = \sum_{i=1}^3 E(X_i^2)$$

Comment: In fact, this should be obvious, because $E(\sum_{i,j=1}^nX_iX_j)$ is just a pairing of random variables. If they have distinct index, by the iid property you can separate them, and the mean is zero, thefore random variables with distinct terms are canceled. If they have the same index, you got $E(X_i^2)$, which is what is left after all.

Comment: Pay attention on the indexes, the first sum has $n^2$ terms (i,j=1...n), the second one has $n$ terms (i=1...n).

Comment: You are imposing the special case of a standard Normal variable, rather than the more general case (with general solution) to which I am referring. There is no real reason to restrict the analysis here to the standard Normal, as the problem of interest is a general problem with general solution.

Comment: The question is about Normal Distribution.

Comment: No - the question is about random variable software, which you have illustrated with an example. But the solution which you seek is a general solution, to which your equation does not apply, and is potentially misleading to others. And no - it doesn't even hold for the Normal distribution ... only for the standard Normal.

Comment: ...I think you can't help me, let it go.

Comment: You are right, the question is about a software and I just used that formula as an example. The strange thing is someone taking an example and saying it doesn't work in general. Of course not, it is an example! 
Anyway, this example was made to show how a human being is able to work with $n$ random variables (don't specifying the value of $n$) and get relevant results using only symbolic calculations. I wonder if some software could do the same. Until this moment, Mathematica appears to work only with a specified number of random variables. Maybe I'm wrong about this, and I want to be.

Comment: No offence meant re clarification. The _mathStatica_ 'moment of moment' functions operate on arbitrary power sums $s_r$, where $s_r=\sum _{i=1}^n X_i^r$ (univariate or multivariate). These are expressed in terms of symbolic $n$. The solution is always a function of _n_. If you look at the examples in the chapter, this will be much clearer.

Comment: Sorry if a was rude. I'm really grateful for your effort to help.

Comment: No problem ... :)